# What is the best form to develop an asp.net web app video player that supports All Format Videos in all Browsers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, video

Hope you can help me in this question.

I'm Developing a media center web app in asp.net using HTML5 - JQuery and I want to play all this format videos (.avi, .mp4, .mov, .wmv, .flv, .swf (Optional)) in all browsers (IE, Safari, Chrome, Firefox and Opera).

So, I tried some options, using the HTML5 Object tag; the first one uses Windows Media player, the WMP plays .avi, .mp4, .mov, .wmv nicely but only works in Internet Explorer :(

```
<object id="MediaPlayer" width="800" height="600" classid="CLSID:22D6F312-B0F6-11D0-94AB-0080C74C7E95" standby="Loading Windows Media Player..." type="application/x-oleobject">
            <param name="FileName" value="Download/ClubMelgar.mov"/>
            <param name="ShowControls" value="true"/>
            <param name="ShowStatusBar" value="false"/>
            <param name="ShowDisplay" value="false"/>
            <param name="autostart" value="true"/>
            <embed type="application/x-mplayer2" src="Download/ClubMelgar.mov" name="MediaPlayer" width="192" height="190" showcontrols="1" showstatusbar="0" showdisplay="0" autostart="0"> </embed>
        </object>
```

The second option is similar to the first, but I´m using Quicktime Player, the Quicktime plays in all browsers except the most important (Chrome) :( and plays some media formats (mov,MPEG-4 (.mp4, .m4v))

```
 <object classid="clsid:02bf25d5-8c17-4b23-bc80-d3488abddc6b" width="320" height="180" codebase="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab">
            <param name="src" value="Download/ClubMelgar.mov"/>
            <param name="autoplay" value="true"/>
            <param name="controller" value="false"/>
            <embed src="Download/ClubMelgar.mov" width="320" height="180" autoplay="true" controller="false" pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/">             </embed>
        </object>
```

The third option was use the HTML5  tag  but suppports .mp4 and .ogg files only :(

```
<video height="272" width="480" preload="auto" controls="controls">
    <source src="html5Demo.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.420E01E, mp4a.40.2"'/>
    <source src="html5Demo.ogg" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'/>
</video>
```

So I need some orientation in what is the best way to play all video file formats using HTML5 or Jquery and the same time compatible with all internet browsers.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: there are a lot of client side plugings that already do what you need, do not reinvent the weel, have a look at this one http://jplayer.org/

Comment: Thanks for yout answer.
Can I embeed that plugins using the html5 object tag?

Answer (score 0):

I think flowplayer will help you in that give it a try is is open source an easy to integrate in the web application you just need to download it and references it js and swf files and you will be good to go, more over it have plugin that support streaming  devices such as iphone, and ipad.